# How to style Meteor.js loginButtons?

Tags: meteor

The docs specify to use the template `{{> loginButtons}}` to implement the default login buttons.

What is the best way to apply my own styles to this?

- Rewrite a new template (how would this be done?)
- Add styles to my CSS files marked `!important`
- Other?

Comment: There's this [useraccounts meteor package](http://useraccounts.meteor.com/) with various different styles and one unstyled. It's probably a lot easier to use than trying to style accounts-ui

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It turns out a combination of the two ideas can be used. After delving into [the accounts-ui package](http://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/accounts-ui), it turns out that it contains only one `.less` file. The actual template is included in [accounts-ui-unstyled](http://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled), which is automatically included when `accounts-ui` is added to a `meteor` project.

Hence, the CSS can be removed as follows:

```
meteor remove accounts-ui
meteor add accounts-ui-unstyled
```

You are then left with [the raw HTML](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons.html), which can be styled as you choose.

Comment: It seems there's a warning comment not to use these templates directly.. And a question: How then do you modify the behavior? (dropdown for example) do you re-create all the accounts-ui package locally?

Comment: Where's the warning comment? I just copied in the `less` to a file in my client directory and modified it as I needed

Comment: but what do you do when you want to disable dropdown or change the HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure - I didn't have to do that. I'd have a look at the `accounts-ui-unstyled` package - maybe you could just copy the Js over?

Answer (score 11):

Creating your own templates would definitely give you more control.

You create a template by using the "template" tag:

```
<template name="player">
  <div class="player {{selected}}">
    <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
    <span class="score">{{score}}</span>
    <span class="wins"> {{wins}} </span>
    <span class="losses"> {{loss}} </span>
  </div>

</template>
```

**OR** You can check the "classes" or the "id" of the login buttons after they are rendered on a webpage, using "Inspect Element" on Chrome, And the use those classes as CSS selectors to style them accordingly.

For example:

HTML:

```
//The login button has a class of loginButton
<button class="loginButton"> Login! </button>
```

CSS:

```
#Then you can Have a style for the login button as:
.loginButton{
     width: 100px;
     background-color: cyan;
}
```

Comment: Where can I see the definition for the `loginButtons` template, so that I know which Handlebars Expressions I can use?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good question. I suggest you check out the meteor documentation, or better off.. look at the meteor source on github.

Comment: Ah! I found it! https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/accounts-ui

Comment: Excellent, I have worked out how to do it based on your answer. I'll be posting my own answer to the question, as your answer didn't document the entire procedure, but I'm upvoting yours, because it pointed me in the right direction

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447184/meteor-accounts-login-forms-change-html-remove-dropdown-js

Answer (score 2):

Create your own `html` template similar to this below. Style it to your taste.

`meteor add accounts-password accounts-ui`

```
                <template name="login">
                     <form class="login-form">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3>Login</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Email</label>
                                    <input type="email"  class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email address">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </template>
```

You can now call `Meteor.loginWithPassword` in the template event like so:

```
Template.login.events({
    'submit .login-form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = e.target.email.value;
        var password = e.target.password.value;
      Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password,function(error){
            if(error) {
                //do something if error occurred or 
            }else{
               FlowRouter.go('/');
            }
        });
     }
 });
```

You can create another form for registration as well.

Just call `Accounts.createUser(object, callback);`

Comment: Simply the best.