# Meteor: Location of CSS for login button

Tags: javascript, meteor

I can't find the css files for the login buttons provided by the `accounts-ui` package.

when i look in `.meteor/local/build/static/packages`

I see only `bootstrap` and i can't find it with a comprehensive search on my mac.

Even though i see in the javascript console that its in `packages/accounts-ui`

Help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use firebug to find out the class and id and use that to change the styles. But yes, a separate css would keep things clean

Comment: does that actually change the file permanently?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15034053/1175709

Comment: What I suggested basically is to override the current styles using your custom CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the accounts-ui package is in:

```
.meteor/local/build/static-cacheable/packages
```

and not `static`