# Customize meteor loginButtons helper to display my account button

Tags: authentication, meteor

I would like to customize meteor loginButtons helper to add a "my account" option like in Telescope :

- https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope

In this project, they use the loginButtons helper :

- https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope/blob/master/client/views/common/nav.html

And have some custom template for sign in and sign up :

- https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope/blob/master/client/views/users/user_signin.html
- https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope/blob/master/client/views/users/user_signup.html

But I don't see where I can create a custom template for when the user is logged in, that would display :

- change password
- my account
- log out

I have read :
[How to style Meteor.js loginButtons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025621/how-to-style-meteor-js-loginbuttons)

But it's only about CSS

And watched : 
https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/97d0164c-8f71-46fe-819b-df8df3704546

But it doesn't use the {{loginButtons}} helper

I use bootstrap and accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown.

Comment: There's [this set of packages](http://useraccounts.meteor.com/) which includes many different styles and options

Comment: update for future users: https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/bootstrap as above link is dead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you're looking for is [here:](https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope/blob/6341474a77c96508df9a31c580420dc7224d3ace/client/views/common/nav.js#L20)

```
Template.nav.rendered = function() {
  if(!Meteor.user()) {
    $('.login-link-text').text("Sign Up/Sign In");
  } else {
    $('#login-buttons-logout').before('<a href="/account" class="account-link button">My Account</a>');
  }
};
```

Comment: Thx, I don't know how I missed that

Comment: Also, if you want to hook events to the new button, you can use `Template._loginButtonsLoggedInDropdown.events({'click .account-link': function (evt, tmpl) { ... } }`.

Comment: But ``Template.nav.rendered`` is only executed at the first visit of the site. When you are logging out, or logging in, is this rendered code executed? I guess not, because the navbar is not rendered again?

Comment: @John: You're right. This answer was made before Meteor 0.8.x. `rendered` callback was called more often back then. In current version you'd need to place the code in a different place, such as the template helper. In the future, there will be a redraw event handler for such use cases.

Comment: 2017 checking in. would love this to be native in meteor.