# How to remove the dropdown from accounts package

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, meteor-accounts

I am using `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` and I want to take out the dropdown feature.

I know it is possible with `accounts-ui` package, by using `jamielob:accounts-ui-no-dropdown` package. But the same package didn't work with `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` package.

are there any alternatives to serve my purpose?

Comment: this may help https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/issues/74

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial (http://www.chaosstuff.com/2015/01/meteor-accounts-with-custom-login-form.html)

The author utilized  meteor-template-extension to alter some specific behaviors of the button by keeping the others things untouched.

The steps are briefly first creating your own template which utilizes the original one.

```
<template name="My_loginButtonsLoggedOutDropdown">
    <div class="container">
<section class="panel">
        <header class="panel-heading">
            <strong>Welcome</strong> 
        </header>
        {{> _loginButtonsLoggedOutAllServices}}
    </section></div>
</template>
```

Then replacing the original one with the one you created
    `Template.My_loginButtonsLoggedOutDropdown.replaces("_loginButtonsLoggedOutDropdown")`;

And finally some styling stuff

```
.panel {
    width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    border-radius:2px;
}

.panel-heading {
    border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
    border-top-right-radius:3px;
    border-top-left-radius:3px;
    border-radius:2px 2px 0 0;
    padding:10px 15px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

You can also check this thread as well for some other alternative ideas [How do I style Meteor's loginButton to not be a dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542999/how-do-i-style-meteors-loginbutton-to-not-be-a-dropdown)

I think these links might help you to solve your problem.